# Calling JS Function From C# Not Working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Afternoon,

I have been able to call JavaScript functions from my C# before and it worked fine. For some reason this time the function is not getting hit when i breakpoint the code.

So this is my C# method.

```
    public void tester()
    {
        string returnResult = HttpContext.Current.Session["result"].ToString();

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alerify", "alerify('" + returnResult + "');", true);
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alerify", "alerify(" + returnResult + ");", true);
    }
```

You can see that i have tried different methods but the function is still not getting hit.

This is the JavaScript function i want to call.

```
    function alerify(e) {
        alert(e);
        if (e == "InvalidDates") {
            alertify.error("gfgsdggfsdgfsdfd");
        }
    }
```

I am thinking that i am missing somthing but i just don't know what.

Comment: Please show your code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: @SonerGönül Sorry, i will edit the post with the code.

Answer (score 3):

As it's a string value it needs apostrophes (or quotation marks) to be a string literal in the JavaScript code:

```
... "alerify('" + returnResult + "');" ...
```

Comment: The problem is still occurring.

Comment: @BenClarke: Do you get any error message in the console log?

Comment: @BenClarke: Are you sure that the server code actually runs?

Comment: Yes, i have debugged the server code and it hits the line.

Comment: @BenClarke: What kind of request is running the server code? Does `RegisterStartupScript` have a chance to put any code in the page?